# How to pass random integer to index value using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-ui-automation

I am new to Swift Using following code to generate a random Integer. which is working fine.

```
let lower : UInt32 = 3
let upper : UInt32 = 8
let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower
print(randomNumber)
```

With the generated random integer I am trying to pass it in following instead of statictexts i would like to pass the index value and tap the Element. As I have very big list of **table cells** I want to select a random one from them.

```
tablesQuery.cells.staticTexts["ABC"].tap()
```

Comment: `cells.element(boundedBy: randomIndex).tap()`

Comment: @Astoria tried that but getting following error "Cannot call value of non-function type XCUIElement"

Comment: What version of Swift do you use? `(boundBy:)` of course.

Comment: @Astoria fixed it as I am passing the randomNumber as UInt32 it was showing the error. `cells.element(boundBy: UInt(randomNumber)).tap()`. This worked for me.